WSL able to touch file but mkdir yields Permission denied
I am relaying my SSH connection and I want to restrict the ability of the remote user to view my files. I set umask = 027 in /etc/wsl.conf so that the Windows filesystem is mounted such that another user cannot read or write to the Windows filesystem. However, it seems to also affect the local user in some way as I can no longer mkdir as the local user using either
mkdir test

or
sudo mkdir test

both yield Permission denied error
However, I can
touch test

with no problem. I have checked that ownership of the current folder is the local user logged into wsl.

Are you sure this is a problem with the target permissions? What is the complete, exact error message? Could you possibly have removed the mkdir program's own execute permission (check with ls -l /usr/bin/mkdir)?

@steeldriver The complete output is mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied. The ls -l command yields -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 68096 Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/mkdir so I should have the right to execute. ls -l /usr/bin/touch yields similar -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 92672 Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/touch

It was due to the automount option I entered previously:
[automount]
options="case=dir"

seems to trigger this issue consistently. Also documented on the WSL Github. One needs to set the case sensitivity of the directories outside of WSL first.
